# Cards with different length descriptions are misaligned

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a [`<Card.Group>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/views/card/) from Sematic-UI-react. I have a couple rows of cards with differing description lengths which causes the height of each card to misaligned with the others in the row. I tried setting `<Card style={{ height: "100%" }}>` on each card and using `flex:1` but that throws all the cards in the same row.

I have a linked sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-card-extra-content-toggle-526f2).

I'll post the relevant code below as well

```
 <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3}>
    <Card fluid color="blue" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
      <Card.Content description="Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat. Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat. Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat." />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Extra content for card #0"
        onToggle={toggleCard(0)}
        open={state[0]}
      />
    </Card>
    <Card color="red" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
      <Card.Content description="'Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ac commodo diam, et tincidunt massa. Sed aliquet tortor purus, in pulvinar enim mattis ac. Maecenas vestibulum cursus lorem, quis fermentum enim lacinia a. Ut nec feugiat nisl. Morbi finibus hendrerit diam, id iaculis nibh feugiat sed. Sed non justo turpis. Fusce neque quam, facilisis eu aliquam vitae, hendrerit nec nulla. Integer metus sapien, dictum eget viverra et, dictum in lectus. Integer vitae dolor ut libero dictum tristique eget non nunc. Suspendisse diam urna, pretium sed elementum sed, fermentum eu leo. Donec augue tortor, rhoncus id pulvinar ac, fringilla eu est. Duis et ante tristique dui molestie maximus at ut enim. Curabitur facilisis tempor lorem quis scelerisque. Maecenas enim leo, mollis at egestas in, vulputate eget risus."
        onToggle={toggleCard(1)}
        open={state[1]}
      />
    </Card>{" "}
    <Card color="blue" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
      <Card.Content description="'Elliotying guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Extra content for card #2"
        onToggle={toggleCard(2)}
        open={state[2]}
      />
    </Card>{" "}
    <Card color="blue" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
      <Card.Content description="'Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Extra content for card #3"
        onToggle={toggleCard(3)}
        open={state[3]}
      />
    </Card>{" "}
    <Card color="blue" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
      <Card.Content description="'Elliot is ville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Extra content for card #4"
        onToggle={toggleCard(4)}
        open={state[4]}
      />
    </Card>{" "}
    <Card color="blue" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
      <Card.Content description="'Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville  Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Extra content for card #5"
        onToggle={toggleCard(5)}
        open={state[5]}
      />
    </Card>{" "}
  </Card.Group>
```

Comment: Hi DJ2, see my solution below, let me know if that helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the display to `flex` on the `Card.Group` component. Now in the parent `Card` component, we will give it a style of `alignSelf: "flex-start"`, that way the individual cards will not stretch when another card is expanded.

See Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-card-extra-content-toggle-dimkm

```
  <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3} style={{ display: "flex" }}>
    <Card fluid color="blue" style={{ alignSelf: "flex-start" }}>
      <Card.Content
        header="Elliot"
        textAlign="center"
        style={{ maxHeight: "45px" }}
      />
      <Card.Content
        style={{ flex: "1", minHeight: "275px" }}
        description="Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat. Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat. Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat."
      />
      <ExtraContentAccordion
        content="Extra content for card #0"
        onToggle={toggleCard(0)}
        open={state[0]}
      />
    </Card>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. Is there a way to not extend the height of all the cards in the row when one particular card is expanded to show the `extra` content?

Comment: @DJ2 cfor that to work we would have to establish a minHeight, is that alright?

Comment: That's fine. This would just be applied to each card, right?

Comment: @DJ2 That is correct. I have an updated sandbox for you here: codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-card-extra-content-toggle-dimkm